# Assign each aggregate value to seperate variable in R and display it in HTML

Tags: html, r

I am using the following R script to calculate a monthly CpK number:

```
mydf <- read.csv('file.csv', header = TRUE, sep=",")
date <- strptime(mydf$PDATETIME, "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S")
plot(date,mydf$MEAS_AVG,xlab='Date',ylab='MEAS_AVG',main='year')
abline(h=mydf$TARG_MIN,col=3,lty=1)
abline(h=mydf$TARG_MAX,col=3,lty=1)
grid(NULL,NULL,col="black")
legend("topright", legend = c(" ", " "), text.width = strwidth("1,000,000"), lty = 1:2, xjust = 1, yjust = 1, title = "Data")
myavg <-mean(mydf$MEAS_AVG, na.rm=TRUE)
newds <- (mydf$MEAS_AVG - myavg)^2
newsum <- sum(newds, na.rm=TRUE)
N <- length(mydf$MEAS_AVG) - 1
newN <- 1/N
total <- newN*newsum
sigma <- total^(1/2)
USL <- mean(mydf$TARG_MAX, na.rm=TRUE)
LSL <- mean(mydf$TARG_MIN, na.rm=TRUE)
cpk <- min(((USL-myavg)/(3*sigma)),((myavg-LSL)/(3*sigma)))
cpkmonthly <- aggregate(mydf$MEAS_AVG, na.rm=TRUE, list(month=months(as.Date(mydf$PDATETIME))), mean)
monthlycpk <- by(mydf$MEAS_AVG, na.rm=TRUE, list(month=months(as.Date(mydf$PDATETIME))), mean)
cpk 'variable to store the entire year's CpK number
cpkmonthly 'variable to store the each month's mean CpK number
```

So far, the above script correctly goes through all the code assigns values to the cpkmonthly and cpk variables. Their outputs are as follows:

```
> cpk
[1] 0.5892231

> cpkmonthly
month         x
1  April 0.2456467
2 August 0.2415564
3   July 0.2456895
4   June 0.2541071
5  March 0.1234333
6    May 0.4321418
```

**Question:** How to I break apart the appregated "cpkmonthly" variable and assign a seperate variable for each entry? Ideally, I would like each to go into an array, because I would like to have the final output variable be in a HTML display string.

```
SudoCode:
cpkmonth[1] = April
cpkvalue[1] = .245...
cpkmonth[2] = August
cpkvalue[2] = .2415...
...
```

I would like the final table in HTML to look like this:

[image: Ideal HTML]

So the final output variable would need to be in this format:

```
<tr><td>"Total Cpk"</td><tdcpkmonth[0]</td><td>cpkmonth[1]</td><td>...</td></tr>
<tr><td>"cpk"</td><tdcpkvalue[0]</td><td>cpkvalue[1]</td><td>...</td></tr>
```

For the HTML, I have tried using toJSON/RJSON,R2HTML,HTMLUtil, and a few others, but I am simply looking for one output variable. Is this possible?

Comment: does't `cpkmonth = cpkmonthly$month` give what you want? (except R isn't 0 indexed)

Comment: Have you tried the `xtable` package? Printing an xtable object allows HTML output.

Comment: @Justin If I run `cpkmonthly$month`, it parses the month variable fine, but how to I parse the aggregated values?

Comment: `cpkmonthly$x`? or `cpkmonthly[,2]`

Comment: @Justin Given your help, I was able to accomplish the task. Do you want to type an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to access both of these columns using the `$` syntax:

```
cpkmonth = cpkmonthly$month
cpkvalue = cpkmonthly$value
```

you can also use `[`:

```
cpkmonth = cpkmonthly['month']
```